# facebook sponsored result (typeahead) cost is always zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I target a campaign and chose a page_type='typeahed', I get the reach estimation but the costs (CPM & CPC) are 0.
[About sponsored result.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/sponsored-results/)
Why I don't get the costs?

**an example call:**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/act_MY_AD_ACCOUNT_ID\/reachestimate?currency=USD&targeting_spec={"countries":["CA"],"page_types":["typeahead"]}&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**an example response:**

```
{
   "users": 20,
   "bid_estimations": [
      {
         "location": 3,
         "cpc_min": 0,
         "cpc_median": 0,
         "cpc_max": 0,
         "cpm_min": 0,
         "cpm_median": 0,
         "cpm_max": 0
      }
   ],
   "imp_estimates": [

   ],
   "data": {
      "users": 20,
      "bid_estimations": [
         {
            "location": 3,
            "cpc_min": 0,
            "cpc_median": 0,
            "cpc_max": 0,
            "cpm_min": 0,
            "cpm_median": 0,
            "cpm_max": 0
         }
      ],
      "imp_estimates": [

      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we are also ohaving the same issue, but i noticed that you are not sending "targeted_entities" and in your case this may be the issue. 
'targeting={ "countries": ["US"],"targeted_entities":[194699337231859, 5281959998],"page_types":["typeahead"]}'

Comment: I added the 'targeted_entities' param but I still got 0 for the costs.